# ¿Como puedo hacer una tabla que me organice actividades de mantenimiento preventivo dependiendo la periodicidad, alguna idea?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Quisiera porfavor pedirles una idea de como puedo implementar este sistema, para mandar llamar las actividades de mantenimeinto dependiendo de la periodicidad.

**Esta imagen representa el excel al que me debo guiar para hacerlo web**

[image]
Hasta ahorita solo llevo esto, agregar actividades pero no se como hacerle para tomarla periodicidad y me la arroje en una tabla aparte dependiendo claro de que periodicidad sea,si es diaria pues se mostrara todos los dias esa misma atividad en la tabla. 
Ahorita la frecuencia solo la tengo en puro texto, pero pues asi no me sirve de nada porque yo necesito que haya una funcion que cheque la frecuencia de cada actividad para que dependiendo si es diaria pues me la arroje en una tabla de actividades diarias que se tengan que realizar, tambien suponiendo que habra actividades que seran cada mes, cada 15 dias cada 3 meses etc. ahorita lo que no tengo muy claro, es como llevar a cabo esa funcion, quisiera si pueden alguien me de una idea, 
que de antemano agradeceria!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿El valor de `Periodicidad/Frecuencia` cómo está guardado?, ¿es un `texto`?. Para obtener la tabla de actividades; ésta debe tener por parámetro la Periodicidad/Frecuencia y la función recibe este valor como parámetro para filtrar los resultados.

Comment: pues realmente solo agrege el campo para darme una idea, pero no se como deba de ser ese campo para que tome en cuenta la periodicidad de cada activida, me imaginio que debe de haber una funcion que creo yo deba seleccionar aquellas frecuencias o periodicidades que cumplan y cuando se realicen las actividades debe de haber un boton que tendra una funcion que resete ese contador y pues vuelva a contar, algo asi es mi idea